# Continuous Filter design for measure signals from Boost Converter out

Tags: filter, dc-dc-converter, signal, boost, filtering

So, I found a simulation that uses PID to control the voltage of a DC bus, for voltage measure the author use a "func transfer" in simulink. I wish to know what kind of filter he design and how can I design a filter like this.

[image]
[image]

There is any way to find the behavior of this filter and indicate how design something like this ? I search a litte bit but not found any transf fcn with "1e" elements in the denominator

Comment: 1e-2 is a method of writing \$1\cdot 10^{-2}\$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a first order low pass filter.

A first order, low pass filter, has a transfer function of the form \$\frac{1}{\tau s + 1}\$  where \$\tau\$ is the filter time constant. in the analogue domain such a filter can be realized with a resistor and a capacitor resulting in \$\tau = RC\$

This person has created a 1st order low pass filter with a time constant of 1e-2 which creates a 1st order low pass filter with a cuttoff frequency at \$f_c = \frac{1}{2 \pi \tau} = 15.9Hz\$

Please NOTE: this is a continuous filter and not a digital filter. You can realise the digital equivalent via the difference equation of a 1st order filter:

\$y_i = \alpha x_i + (1+\alpha)y_{i-1}\$

where \$\alpha = \frac{\Delta_T}{\tau + \Delta_T}\$

Comment: Thank you John. Could you please tell me how can I increase the order of this continuous filter ?

Comment: Ahh that's a different question and even then not really one. A digital 2nd order (look up biquad) an analogue (look up salen key) in simulink (complete the quadratic in the transfer function box)

Comment: @SmLord if you just need the job done quickly then you can filter the signal twice, i.e. take the output of the first filter and filter it again. This will double the gain roll-off, though can be designed better with more thought.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen is that meant for me?

Comment: @JonRB Good God, I have no idea why I mixed up the names. I'll delete that and address it properly. Sorry for the mess. :-)

Comment: @SrnLord Rather than just mindlessly throwing stuff in there and expecting it to work, wouldn't you say it would be better to first read a bit about the consituent basics? Otherwise, you next question(s) will be "why isn't this working?" with, no doubt, a simple explanation that you could have seen by yourself, if...